# trying to call second form from the first form in visual studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

I'm trying to call **Form2** from **MyForm** in visual studio

```
#include "Form2.h"
#pragma once

...

private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    Form2^ xx = gcnew Form2();
    xx->ShowDialog();
}
```

but i get an error:

> *identifier "Form2" is undefined*

And I don't understand why. I already included "Form2.h" in MyForm.h.
How can it be solved?

Comment: I assume that you *do* have a `Form2` class definition in Form2.h. Isn't it eclosed in a namespace?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have `#include "MyForm.h"` inside of your Form2.h.

What you need to do is move all of the method contents out of the .h files, and put them in .cpp files. After you've done that, you should be able to move many of the `#include` statements from the .h to the .cpp as well.

By #including two header files from each other, you end up in situations like this. The #pragma once is breaking the recursion, but whichever one ends up getting compiled first won't see the other one, since it comes later in the post-processed file. By leaving just the class definition in the header file, and moving the contents into a .cpp file, now the header files don't need to refer to each other, only the .cpp needs to refer to both header files, so everything compiles cleanly.